# Can ydn-db be used as a direct WebSQL polyfill

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-sql, polyfills, ydn-db

I am building a webkit-based browser and want to provide a polyfill for WebSQL. I found ydn-db but if I inject the polyfill into the webpage, will it just work automatically? Meaning, when WebSQL javascript APIs are called such as `window.openDatabase` or `executeSql`, will these APIs be polyfilled ?

Answer (score 0):

YDN-DB has basic SQL query engine on top of IndexedDB (or any supported storage engine). But it is not fully featured.

Look at

- http://alasql.org/
- https://github.com/jlongster/absurd-sql